Does bhashya mean bhashantaran?
Bhashya is different form bhashantaran of bhashya is same as bhashantaran
What is mean by bhashya ?
What is mean by bhashantaran ?

Bhashya means commentary and Bhashantara means translation or a different version.


Source.
